# OAuth 2.0 in C++ Builder XE2

Tags: c++, rest, oauth-2.0, c++builder

How to implement OAuth 2.0 authorization in C++ Builder XE2? Starting with version XE 5, there was a library REST Client Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarcadero's REST framework has a [`TOAuth2Authenticator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/REST.Authenticator.OAuth.TOAuth2Authenticator) class.

The **Accessing Google Tasks API** example in Embarcadero's [RESTDemo Sample](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE7/en/RESTDemo_Sample) demonstrates the use of OAuth 2.

**Update**: sorry, I didn't read the question clearly enough.  There is no built-in OAuth support in XE2.  You will have to use a third-party library, or write your own implementation.